# Docker swarm multiple instances of service each with different configurations

Tags: docker, configuration, swarm

In Docker I wish to run multiple instances of the same application. These applications all need their own configuration (db name/port) preferably fed via a file but any solution will do really.

I think I should run this in swarm mode. But I can't figure out how to pass different configurations to all the different tasks spawned by the service. Does docker swarm support this use case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting it wrong. The replication mode in docker is to bring up more nodes for the same task with a built in loadbalancer. So having different configurations for each instance would deny this use case partially.

You option is to use different service per different configuration.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse different services but still swarm. How do large swarms manage their configurations?

Comment: You can start with environment variables. Get them in the docker scope and at the start of your container, use these variables to change your configurations and then start your application